# How to setup magento2 pwa nginx

Tags: magento2, nginx, pwa

I have set up Magento backend on eample.com and want to run PWA on subdomain pwa.example.com, I have set up the virtual host in Nginx for both, However, the backend is running but PWA on pwa.example.com is not running?

I'm using [Siminia - Magento 2 PWA Studio Theme by SimiCart](https://github.com/Simicart/siminia-public)